# How to access properties inside a Node4j Collection

Tags: neo4j

I have a collection of nodes in Node4j. How to access properties inside individual nodes in a foreach?

```
MATCH(bal:BalanceSheetItemBalance)
WITH COLLECT(bal) as bals
FOREACH(i in RANGE(0,length(bals)-1) |
MATCH(val:ValueBasisLayerBalance{BalanceSheetItemID:(bals[i].BalanceSheetItemID})
CREATE (bals[i])-[:Layers]->(val))
```

Accessing by the above technique gives me an error in syntax.

```
Invalid input '.': expected whitespace, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR or ')' (line 4, column 61 (offset: 160))
"MATCH(val:ValueBasisLayerBalance{BalanceSheetItemID:(bals[i].BalanceSheetItemID})"
                                                             ^
```

I need to Match the BalanceSheetItemID in bals[i] with the BalanceSheetItemID in ValueBasisLayerBalance nodes. Is there any other way to access that specific property inside the nodes in the collection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your query correctly, but I think you want to create a relationship between `BalanceSheetItemBalance` and `ValueBasisLayerBalance` nodes which have same `BalanceSheetItemID`?

Try:

```
MATCH (bal:BalanceSheetItemBalance), (val:ValueBasisLayerBalance)
WHERE bal.BalanceSheetItemID = val.BalanceSheetItemID
CREATE (bal)-[:LAYERS]->(val)
```